# My Text RPG will not run

Tags: python

I have a text based RPG which will not run. Below is the code.

```
import random
import time

#variable names with character stats
lvl = 1
strength = 0
health = 100
maxhealth = health * lvl

#monster dictionaries which display stats
imp = {'health':10,'attack':1,'speed':20}
killer_ant = {'health':15,'attack':2,'speed':100}
goblin = {'health':5,'attack':3,'speed':4}
monster_dict = {'imp':imp, 'killer_ant':killer_ant, 'goblin':goblin}

#choosing a random monster from monster_dict
counter=0
randNum= random.randint(1,3)
for name,monster_stat in monster_dict.items():
  counter=counter+1
  if counter == randNum:
    print ('The monsters name is', name,monster_stat)

#weapon classes
sword = {'sword':0,'attack':5,'speed':1}
mace = {'mace':0,'attack':10,'speed':2} 
staff = {'staff':0,'attack':15,'speed':3}
weapon_dict2 = {'sword':sword,'mace':mace,'staff':staff}

#class selection somewhat works
class_choice = input("choose a weapon (sword, mace, or staff)")
inventory = [ ]
for name2,character_stat in weapon_dict2.items():
  if class_choice == name2:
    inventory.append(class_choice)
    print('here is your inventory:', inventory)
    print('class choice is valid.')
else:
  print('class choice is invalid.')

    '''
    class choice is invalid sometimes repeats twice or when it is valid, #says its invalid
    '''

battle_choice = input('what do you want to do (use weapon or run away)')
first_turn = True
while first_turn:
  if battle_choice == 'run away':
    if character_stat['speed'] > monster_stat['speed']:
      print('you are faster than monster and you have escaped')
      break
    else:
      print('you cant escape and the monster will fight you')
      break
  if battle_choice == "use weapon":
    while battle_choice == 'use weapon':
      monster_stat['health'] = monster_stat['health'] - character_stat['attack']
      print(monster_stat['health'])
      maxhealth = maxhealth - monster_stat['attack']
      print(maxhealth)
```

The 2 problems, are that

1. The wrong monster is selected, since I see it do the wrong amount of damage.
2. I cannot figure out how to give the player the choice of what to do after the player chooses 'use weapon'.

Comment: What error are you getting.  I presume by "will not run", you mean, it crashes at some stage - so please can you add some details on where.  The second part of the question depends on what you want to happen.

Comment: You have an indent error in the second for loop. Is that present in the original code, or is that from attempting to format the code block?

Comment: Whenever the user inputs, use weapon, "it does not run" with the while loop

Comment: and bendl, I don't see what indent error your talking about.

Comment: @user8507808 if you're still working on this, the else statement should be indented. As it is currently written, it's an else statement to the for loop, which is a pretty strange, albeit valid structure. It's syntactically valid, so it's not throwing an error, but I doubt it's doing what you intended it to do.